# The infamous "sticky" :hover on iPad - how does Google fix it?

Tags: ipad, menu, hover, touch

I have unfortunately stumbled on the issue where, on iPad, a pop-up menu summoned by way of :hover does not disappear from the screen when the user touches an empty area of the page.

The problem is the same described here:

[Hover Behavior on Desktop vs iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15815513/hover-behavior-on-desktop-vs-ipad)

The menu is part of a template I bought, namely:

http://html.realia.byaviators.com/

But... wait a minute... it WORKS on the template's home page? And only on that page -- it doesn't work on any other page of that same template.

I was able to track the behavior down to the point where I found that the reason why it works is the following: initializing a Google map makes the menu behave properly. Just the simplest of maps, with the default options.

Now my question to the experts is: what is that Google does in the map initialization code in order to fix the :hover behavior?

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, can't tell what is that Google does, however the solution is documented in mobile Safari developer's reference.

For a click event to be generated on an area of the document, there must be a click handler attached. For example, clicking on a div will generate a click event only if an onclick="void(0)" handle is presente:

Clicking here triggers event in mobile Safari